# How do you bind to a data-bound UserControl from inside its Resources section?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

I want to bind `ParentSidebar` of `SelectIngredient` to the root `Sidebar` in XAML below. `DataContext` of `Sidebar` is set to some data in code-behind so I can't use it. I want to achieve this without using `ElementName`. Is it possible?

```
<Sidebar x:Class="MyApplication.Sidebar"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Sidebar.Resources>
        <SelectIngredient x:Key="selectIngredient" x:Name="selectIngredient"
                              ParentSidebar="{Binding ???}">
        </SelectIngredient>
    </Sidebar.Resources>

</Sidebar>
```

EDIT:

In the Visual Tree, `Sidebar` is a sibling of `SelectIngredient`. So it's just logically a parent but not actually.

Answer (score 5):

```
<Sidebar.Resources>
    <SelectIngredient x:Key="selectIngredient" x:Name="selectIngredient"
                          ParentSideBar={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=SideBar, AncestorLevel=1}}>
    </SelectIngredient>
</Sidebar.Resources>
```

Comment: Can you please tell what is XXX? Because I want to bind to the `Sidebar` itself. Not to some property of `Sidebar`.

Comment: Won't this bind to `DataContext` of `Sidebar`? I want to bind to `Sidebar` itself.

Comment: No it will bind itself to the SideBar object, not to the datacontext. If you would use the binding as it is stated now in my answer, the value of ParentSidebar would be the Sidebar object.

Comment: Not working. I think it is because the `SelectIngredient` is actually a resource of `Sidebar`. `Sidebar` is not its ancestor in Visual Tree but a sibling.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I guess you will have to use Element name to bind it.